# event not triggering after ajax response Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have following functions

```
      function populateTableData(){
                jQuery('select[name="drg-select"]').change(function() {
                    drgValue=jQuery(this).val();
                    url="http://localhost/url/FetchRecordFromDatabase.php";
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: 'post',
                        url: url,
                        data: {drgValue: drgValue},
                        success:(function(data) {
                            var str = '';
                            jQuery.each(data, function (key, value) {
                                str += '<tr><td id="'+value[0]+'" value="'+value[0]+'">' + value[0] + '</td>'
                                    + '<td id="'+value[1]+'" value="'+value[1]+'">' + value[1] + '</td>'
                                    + '<td id="'+value[2]+'" value="'+value[2]+'">' + value[2] + '</td>'
                                    + '<td id="'+value[3]+'" value="'+value[3]+'">' + value[3] + '</td></tr>';
                            });
                            jQuery('table[name=drg_table] tbody').html(str);
                        })
                    });
                });
            }
```

and

```
        function  fetchValuesForDrgDefinition(url,param) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: url,
                    data: {hospital_name:param},
                    success:(function(data) {
                        drawVisualization(data);
                        jQuery('#hospital_title').html(param);
                    })
                });                         
            }
```

and this is how i am calling them

```
          jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
                populateTableData();
                jQuery("table[name='drg_table'] tr td").click(function(){  
                    var hospital_name=jQuery(this).text();
                    fetchValuesForDrgDefinition(urlTable,hospital_name);
                });

            });
```

The problem is when following functions are called for 1st time they work, but if i 1st trigger **populateTableData** and then try **fetchValuesForDrgDefinition** event dont occur. P.S events to these functions are called independently but if called one 1 after other , the later called donot trigger.

Comment: add `error` callback and check the error code (if it throws the error cb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    populateTableData();
    jQuery("table[name='drg_table']").on("click", "tr td", function(){  
        var hospital_name=jQuery(this).text();
        fetchValuesForDrgDefinition(urlTable,hospital_name);
    });
});
```

The problem occurs because you're adding the `td`'s dynamically and the event is delegated before they even exist. If the table is a static element it should work for you. If it isn't static delegate the event to its next static parent (or to the document).

**EDIT: Using an old version of jQuery**

If you're using a jQuery version lower than 1.7 use the `live` function:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    populateTableData();
    jQuery("table[name='drg_table'] tr td").live("click", function(){  
        var hospital_name=jQuery(this).text();
        fetchValuesForDrgDefinition(urlTable,hospital_name);
    });
});
```

**EDIT: Conflict with other libraries**

If you're using another library besides jQuery some conflicts can occur.
Use jQuery's `noConflict` function to prevent that.

It's usually the best to insert this right after you include the jQuery library and before you include any other library:

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

Comment: yes thx, after correction this is what i am getting TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function

Comment: @temp-learn you have to delegate the event to the closest static parent and enyce12 has answered it quite fine.

Comment: @temp-learn Which version of jQuery are you using? I edited my answer.

Comment: @enyce12: thx this worked but i am loading jquery from here 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">, if this is old can your link me here new 1?

Comment: @enyce12:bind() was working after you edited and replaced live() its giving some strange error

Comment: +1 for edit, and now its working, if there was another up vote allowed you would have had it from me, Thx to you and all who contributed.

Comment: Version 1.9.1 isn't that old but you can get the recent here: http://jquery.com/ (scroll down). You probably have some conflicts with other libraries you're using. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried binding using [jquery On](http://api.jquery.com/on/), as below -

```
 jQuery("table[name='drg_table'] tr td").on('click',function(){  
                    var hospital_name=jQuery(this).text();
                    fetchValuesForDrgDefinition(urlTable,hospital_name);
});
```

It is meant for very similar scenarios. Where DOM elements are created dynaically.

Comment: i am getting this error TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function

Answer (score 1):

for elements created dynamically, you need to attach event on a document level so that whenever documents add elements on the page(in this case dynamic elements), it also attaches the vent associated with it.

```
$(document).on("click", "table[name='drg_table']", function() {
    populateTableData();
    var hospital_name=$(this).text();
    fetchValuesForDrgDefinition(urlTable,hospital_name);
});
```